# check balance before and after transaction with chai

Tags: hardhat, testing, chai

I'm writing the test cases for a contract, and I have a problem trying to match the balance, because of the transaction gas. what is the correct way to do it?

```
 it("should allow the owner of the campaign to withdraw funds if the campaign is successful", async () => {
const target = ethers.utils.parseEther("1");

await contract.connect(aliceAccount).createCampaign(
  "Test Campaign",
  "Test Description",
  ethers.utils.parseEther("10"),
  "testimage.jpg"
);

// Bob and Alice donate to the campaign
await contract
  .connect(bobAccount)
  .donateToCampaign(0, { value: ethers.utils.parseEther("5") });
await contract
  .connect(johnAccount)
  .donateToCampaign(0, { value: ethers.utils.parseEther("5") });

// check if the campaign has reached its target
const campaign = await contract.campaigns(0);
expect(campaign.amountCollected).to.equal(ethers.utils.parseEther("10"));
expect(campaign.status).to.equal(2);

// get the balance of the owner before withdrawing funds
const balanceBefore = await ethers.provider.getBalance(aliceAccount.address);

// call the withdrawFunds function
const tx = await contract.connect(aliceAccount).withdrawFunds(0);

// get the balance of the owner after withdrawing funds
const balanceAfter = await ethers.provider.getBalance(aliceAccount.address);


// WHAT IS THE COORECT WAY TO CHECK THIS? the problem is the gas 
expect(balanceAfter == balanceBefore + 10 ether )
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Solve it.

I was calculating the gas used wrong way

```
const gasUsed = receipt.effectiveGasPrice.mul(receipt.cumulativeGasUsed)
```